# Alert Dialog inside an Onclick Listener Method

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

```
  rdmrbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
                alert.setTitle("No Internet access");
                alert.setMessage("You can't reach the discussion from the Offline mode");
                alert.setButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

I want show the mentioned alert when the readmore button("rdmrbtn") is clicked. But it gives me some compile errors. Please would you guyz help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
rdmrbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this).create();
            alert.setTitle("No Internet access");
            alert.setMessage("You can't reach the discussion from the Offline mode");
            alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are NOT setting the "Context" Parameter of AlertDialog.Builder Class correctly.
Try Below, much cleaner approach. Also, define "ok" in your strings.xml file.

```
rdmrbtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {    
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("No Internet access");
                builder.setMessage("You can't reach the discussion from the Offline mode");
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                })
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
```